# how does asterisk [ or similar console application ] achieve "asterisk -r" console

Tags: c++, c, console-application, asterisk

Anyone who is familiar with [asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) knows you can connect to running asterisk application by using "`asterisk -r`" command and looking at what asterisk is up to.

My question is using c/c++ , how is it achieved? what headers / libraries are used? I have been searching around for long but can not find anything relevant.

I have been tasked with developing an app which runs as a daemon and i think it would be good idea to be able to interact with him in similar fashion of asterisk. Currently I am running this in a screen https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNU_Screen but would like to change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When first instance of asterisk is run, it opens socket server which is handling communication with daemon.

`asterisk -r` is nothing more than socket client